# How to find shortest path in a directed graph that has edge weights either 0 or 1 in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I am looking for a way to augment the BFS method used to find the single source shortest paths in an unweighted directed graph and solve the above problem in O(N+M) time. 
where N is the number of vertices, M is the number of edges

I have thought the following:

1. Contract the vertices of the graph that have an edge weight 0 between them. But this would definitely be wrong as then I would be changing the graph's properties and adding new edges to vertices that originally had none.
2. Changing the edge weights to 1 and 2. And then creating dummy vertices in the paths that are of length 2 to convert those edges to edges of weight 1. But this would give the wrong answer.

In more generality, how can I find single source shortest paths in a directed graph when the edge weights are between 0 and MAX in linear time. (MAX is the maximum edge weight)

Comment: BTW in the general case you get `O((n + m) log n)` with Dijkstra using  a binary heap as priority queue. If `MAX` is really small, you could use buckets and a y-fast trie to implement the prio queue, resulting in `O(n)` space and a `O((n + m) * log log (n * MAX))` time (no idea how fast that would be in practice, but I'd really like to know :D)

Comment: Torben Hagerups explanations on [Improved Shortest Paths on the Word RAM](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/tad.takaoka/url/tong/a.pdf) may be helpful to you.

Comment: If you only have MAX different lengths, you can have one queue for vertices at each distance. Basically you're making a constant time priority queue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use bfs with some modifications: maintain a deque instead of a queue and add a vertex to the front of the deque if 0 edge is used and to the back of the deque otherwise.(I mean 0-1 case now)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your approach. From where are you popping/removing elements from your deque and how are you running your algorithm? If I am correct, you are trying to maintain 2 queues but still the algorithm is unclear.

Comment: Pop from the front. Everything else is the same as in usual bfs.

Comment: Pretty cool approach. Very easy to implement too. I like this very much, is it a common thing to do?

Comment: This is really cool! Actually it's just Dijkstra where we notice weight 0 edges would always go to the front of the priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work this out with vertex contraction. Just a hint here:

First form connected components of vertices that are connected by 0-weight edges and select one representative member in every component. This will give you a contracted graph.

Then solve the unweighted problem.

The true path will be formed of "inter-edges" (weight 1) joining the representative members, and "intra-edges", joining vertices within the component, from the incoming inter-edge to the outgoing inter-edge. In other words, you need to be able to find the path from any representative to any other representative.

Comment: Your algorithm will fail in the following case. See this link http://pastebin.com/qzYFJLz0

Comment: Right. Directed makes a difference as you cannot reach any vertex from any other in the same component. I underlooked this.